# Modify a Delphi DFM resource to close upon showing?

Tags: delphi, modal-dialog, reverse-engineering, dfm

Is it possible to edit a DFM (Delphi's form script format) in such a way that a form closes itself when shown?

I don't code in Delphi, so I'm not familiar with how these forms work, but it seems I could put code (but not standard Delphi code as it seems) in the *OnShow* or *OnCreate* events of the form. However, after trying several statements like *Close*, *Exit*, *FormNameExit*, *Destroy*, etc. won't work (a log will be created, stating the error that the value of the OnShow property was invalid, etc.)

The normal way of closing the form is through a button, but the button doesn't have a *OnClick* event, just a property, "**ModalResult = 1**".

Is there a way to make the window close upon opening, some standard function I could put on the OnCreate or OnShow events of the form? Or maybe, creating a checkbox on the form itself, that gives ModalResult = 1? (don't know if this works)

Thanks for any suggestion!
=)

(Note: maybe it's obvious, but I don't have the source.)

Comment: Please clarify why you would want to close the form upon showing; there may be another option.

Comment: Since it's annoying, and I always press the same button. I've thought about coding a small program that clicks the button, but I don't know if it's possible to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Seeing some of your comments added while I typed my text-wall clarifies things a bit.

> I'm guessing that you you're using a resource editor to edit the DFM and modify the behaviour of the app without actually touching the source code?
>
> In this case, the best you could try is to set the `Visible` property to `False`. However, this will have no benefit if the developer 'actively displays the form in code'. (He could have done this by calling `Show`, `ShowModal` or even by explicitly setting the `Visible` property.)
>
> Unfortunately, if this is the case, then there's nothing you can do without modifying the actual source code. This is because the DFM is processed when the form is loaded; i.e. before the developer's code that shows the form. Even looking for a place to set `ModalResult` is useless, because the current `ModalResult` is cleared when `ShowModal` is called.

I don't think I understand exactly what you're trying to do, because it doesn't make sense.
It seems to me that you want the form to be automatically closed as soon as it is shown; and that doesn't make sense. :S
So, if I have understood you correctly, please explain why you would want to do this; there may be a better solution for your actual problem.

However, some general concepts...

- If you want a form to close, you should link it to some action that closes the form. Either put a button on the form, or a menu item.
- Standard forms have a standard Windows mechanism to close them by default. (I.e. the X on the top-right.)
- There are two ways of showing forms, and the way in which it is shown does have an effect on how it will be closed. It can be shown modally (which means it is the only form of the application which will interact with the user), or it can be shown normally (which allows the user to switch between other forms of the application).

  - The point of showing a form modally is that it blocks the flow of your code until the user has finished doing something that was required; it often involves the user providing some form of answer or confirmation.
  - When shown modally, the form should rather be closed with a `ModalResult`.
  - When shown normally, the `ModalResult` has no effect.
- Whenever a form is 'closed', there are a few ways in which this can be done.

  - The form can simply be hidden; it's still there, but invisible. Next time you want to show the form, you just make it visible again.
  - The form can be destroyed; meaning that it no longer exists in memory. If this is done, then next time you want to use the form, you have to recreate it.
  - The attempt to close the form can be actively prevented (Not usually advisable; but may be necessary in specific cases - if for example some information on the form is incorrect).
  - The form may be simply minimised (this is often done with MDI child forms).
- NOTE: There are also a number of attributes on forms (`FormStyle` being the most important) that have an effect on how it behaves, displays, and can be closed. (E.g. MDI Child forms will by default either minimise, or do nothing when closed.)
- **NB**:If the main form of an application is *properly* closed, then the application will shut down.

Now, some of the technicalities...

- As mentioned earlier a form can be displayed either modally, or normally; using either `MyForm.Show;` or `ModalResult := MyForm.ShowModal;`

  - *NOTE*: If the form was shown modally, you then need to check the `ModalResult` to find out the user's answer and act accordingly.
- If you displayed the form modally, you should set the `ModalResult` and the form will close itself. An easy way to do this is to assign a `ModalResult` to the buttons on the form; then the button will automatically set the form's `ModalResult` when clicked.
- If you displayed the form normally, then all you need to do is call `MyForm.Close` at the appropriate point in time. **NB**: Note their are other ways to 'close' a form, but it is better to use this method because it allows you to handle the `OnCloseQuery` event which is a mechanism to confirm whether the form is allowed to close.
- **NOTE**: While closing the form, there are two events that Delphi can call which you can handle in order to modify how the closing of the form behaves:

  - `OnCloseQuery` is called to confirm whether the form is allowed to close.
  - `OnClose` is called to find out how the form should close (as explained previously).

Coming back to your question (which sounds like you want the form closed automatically). Rather than closing the form automatically; just don't bother showing it. This is very easy to do. All forms have a `Visible` property; if set to `True`, Delphi will automatically show the form normally when it is created. So all you need to do is ensure the property is `False`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for being so informative! I'll try to exlain it better. There is a button that closes the form, yet I want to automate that. It uses "ModalResult = 1" to close the form, and the main form freezes while the dialog is shown. I tried "OnShow = FormName.Close", but it crashes and leaves a log saying it's an invalid value for the OnShow property of that form. setting Visible = False doesn't work, maybe because it's a modal form and has to be shown? (but program runs normally). Is there something I could put on FormStyle to make it not be modal anymore? (if this enables invisibility)

Comment: In another approach, is it possible to write code that waits for and closes a modal form? that way, I could code a small program that launches with the main program and pushes the button.

Comment: Yep, as I explained: this is not possible from within the DFM, so you'd have to use an external program. A trivial one could be written; I suggest searching for / posting a question tagged to the Win32 API for some information. Alternatively, automated testing tools are able to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks! I see it may be smarter to simply code some sort of auto-click-the-form's-defeault-button thing. AFAIK, AutoHotkey can do this and even compile into an executable, but I'm not sure. Unless some miracle happens, your answer is choosen =)

Comment: Choosen, and btw, text-walls mean you cared to help! Plus, it was informative and very readable. Thanks =)

Answer (score 2):

Not in DFM. You would have to modify the source.

Comment: Anything that I could do to make it not show at all? If I delete it's resource, even updating the checksum, the program crashes :/

Answer (score 2):

The *OnShow* and *OnCreate* lines you're seeing are only used to give the name of a method that's already defined in the source code. You can't add much functionality at all by modifying the DFM file.

Perhaps the form already has a matching event handler that closes it: the OnClick handler for a close button or menu item, maybe? If so, you could try setting it as the OnShow or OnCreate handler.

You might be able to add a TButton to the form and set its ModalResult -- I don't recall whether you actually need a field in the form class for each control in the DFM -- but that would only work if the form is shown modally, and you'd still have to click it to make the form close.

Comment: Thanks, but could I add anything on the DFM that makes the form not show? Or, close upon showing.  
Regarding adding another control, I can do that, it works for duplicating the button that closes the form, I only have to duplicate the "ModalResult = 1", and it works for closing the form as well. I don't know the name of a checkbox in DFM, but "TCheckBox" doesn't work. And the button doesn't call a function, simply has the ModalResult = 1 thing :( 
 
In short, is there anything I could do in a DFM that will make it not show/self-close/auto-click/show on unexistant monitor/whatever?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this just by editing the DFM, sorry. Writing a separate program that sends WM_CLOSE to the form might be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You really can't do much without the source but move files around or change existing properties.  If you have a MAP file for the program and there are existing events in place (onCreate/OnShow) you could patch the executable to invoke different code for those events, but it won't be easy and you have to insure that you don't inject more code than was there previously or make any external calls to routines which don't exist.